# Examples of Integrable Functions

Tags: real-analysis

What would be and example of a bounded function $f$ such that $| f |$ is integrable, but $f$ is not integrable?

Comment: Define $f$ on the rationals and irrationals separately.

Comment: Take a non-measurable subset $N$ of $[0,\,1]$, let $f = \chi_N - \chi_{[0,\,1]\setminus N}$.

Comment: Do you mean Riemann integrable, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=1, \text{if}\ x \in \mathbb{Q}\\-1,\text{if}\ x \in \mathbb{R-Q}$$

Then, $f$ is not integrable in $[0,1]$, while $|f|$ is integrable.